# Can't remove blurry edge on scroll when using backdrop-filter: blur

Tags: css, filter, scroll, blur, blurry

When trying the glassmorphism style and using the css backdrop-filter, I get a dark blurred edge at the top of the element when scrolling. I feel like it should be an easy fix, but I've tried everything I know (which apparently isn't enough) and can't figure it out. I created a pen so you can see what I'm talking about. For some bewildering reason, you have to open it up in codepen to see the undesired effect.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://www.theuiaa.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/2018_banner.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 200vh;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  background-blend-mode: soft-light;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 50%;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 320px;
  height: 540px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
}

.arrow {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  font-size: 200px;
  line-height: 1;
  color: red;
}

.card p {
  font-size: 32px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="card">
  <div class="arrow"><span>&#129041;</span></div>
<p>As you can see when you scroll down, as soon as the card hits the top of the screen, you get a blurred edge. Not cool...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/alxhrrs/pen/YzGebVj)

Answer (score 1):

I think you found a Chrome issue! *(It doesn't happen in Firefox)*.

I very quickly checked in [chromium bugs](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?q=backdrop-filter&can=2) and did not found anything close.. So I suggest you report it!

**Additionnaly**, I made a test to determine where that black "gradient" was coming from... I changed the `background` color of Codepen's `.main-header`!!

To reproduce, paste that in the console:

```
document.querySelector(".main-header").style.background = "red"
```

The expected result is:

[image: CodePen main header in inspector]

But the surprise is the "gradient" now turned **red**.
You certainly know that the codepen result is an `iframe`... So I think that is called a "paint" issue.

[image: CoderPen main header result]

Comment: well i had found some similar problems regarding chrome, but from something like 2015 so i figured they had fixed it by now. what's odd, or perhaps the answer lies in this...if you run the code snippet, it actually doesn't create the problem. that's why at first, i thought if might be some parameter i was missing...

Comment: `if you run the code snippet, it actually doesn't create the problem` The SO snippet? Yes it creates the problem, but since the "top element" is not perfect black, it may be more subtile to notice.

Comment: ok you're right, if you open it up full screen. sorry, i didn't even know you could do that. but if you open it just on this page when clicking the 'run code snippet' button, i don't see the blur. that's why i thought it might be a matter of needing to place divs within divs etc..

Comment: I made the [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1162743).